# How to BCC email from iPhoto '11

Tags: email, photos.app

iPhoto '11 has beautiful email templates that make it a great choice for sharing pics with friends. I can't seem find a way to send emails with the recipients in a BCC field, forcing me to break a cardinal rule of mass emails--putting all the addresses in the TO field OR first email myself and then forwarding the email, which is kind of a pain.

Any fix for this from iPhoto itself?

Comment: The problem I'm having and the reason I wanted to send this email via iPhoto rather than Mail to begin with, is that the photo I want to send shows up only as an icon in the message. I want to have it show up as a photo. Any ideas on how to make that happen? So, when I draft the email in Mail, either from scratch in Mail, or from iPhoto (with Preferences set to send in Mail), the photo shows up as an icon, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

Go into preferences at the bottom of the "General" tab tell iPhoto to email from Mail instead of iPhoto itself.

The other option, if you don't want to give up on this functionality right inside of iPhoto, you can email it just to yourself and then "resend" it (rather than forward, resend avoids the indentation).

Answer (score 0):

Poking around in iPhoto, I can’t find anything. Looking through the Apple Support Communities suggests that if Apple has implemented it, they’ve hidden it very well!

The only workaround I found, aside the one you mentioned above about forwarding it to yourself, is to set the default mail client as “Mail” in Preferences, then when you send it out, you could use Mail.app’s BCC function. Of course, this isn’t really a workaround, as you lose the iPhoto templates.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Since your username, photo, and a link to your profile automatically appears under your posts, signing your messages is unnecessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about sending directly from iPhoto (via Share → Email) is the layout facilities available, ideal for Christmas greetings and similar. However, the downside to this is the unavailability of the BCC: address line. I personally fail to understand why Apple did not design that in.

The workaround for this that I found is to set up whatever you would like to send out via iPhoto → Mail, and take a screenshot of this (⌘⇧4) which can be added into a regular email. This way we have both: the enhanced layout facility *and* the BCC: line.